# Send Laravel notifications according to custom user locale value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, push-notification

I'm looking for the best approach to build notifications in Laravel based on users locale value (english and spanish).

**SomeController.php** (that sends the notification):

```
Notification::send(User::find($some_id), new CustomNotification($some_parameter));
```

**CustomNotification.php**:

```
class CustomNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    protected $title, $body, $foot;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($some_parameter)
    {
        $this->title = __('Some Title');
        $this->response = __('Some Response');
        $this->foot = 'My WebPage Title';
    }
    ...
}
```

With the CustomNotification construct the values of $title and $response will be translated according to the current user who send the notification, but in this case the admin is the one who sends it, so the values of this variables will be in the admin locale and not the user.

Comment: You'll likely have to define `$user = User::find($some_id)` outside of the `Notification::send()` call so you can pass it to `new CustomNotification($some_parameter, $user)` call, then you can do a `app()->setLocale()` according to the passed `$user` before calling those `__()` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well in this case you should store locale in the users table, then you can send it (or at least his locale) to the notification constructor:

```
$user=User::find($some_id);

Notification::send($user, new CustomNotification($some_parameter,$user));
```

and in your notification class:

```
class CustomNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    protected $title, $body, $foot;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($some_parameter,User $user)
    {
       
        App::setLocale($user->locale??$defaultLocale);

        $this->title = __('Some Title');
        $this->response = __('Some Response');
        $this->foot = 'My WebPage Title';
    }
    ...
}
```

and also like @ManojKiran Appathurai you use [laravel notification localization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#localizing-notifications):

```
 Notification::send($user, new CustomNotification($some_parameter)->locale($user->locale);
```

Comment: I was kinda trying to avoid appeal to the database, but if there's no a better way I guess I'll add the migration.

Comment: I have that column in my users table also

Comment: Laravel has out of box support for [localizing-notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#localizing-notifications)

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai, thanks! , I have included your comment in the answer